# What hides within this mashed-up song?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

The answer hides within this senseless song made from the mashed-up
lyrics of other songs. Each lyric is linked to the song's full lyrics.

> *[Hey, hey, Charlie take a bow,](https://genius.com/Ella-fitzgerald-clap-hands-here-comes-charlie-lyrics)*
>
> *[You deserve an Oscar,](https://genius.com/French-montana-you-deserve-an-oscar-lyrics)*
>
> *[I recall late November,](https://genius.com/Taylor-swift-call-it-what-you-want-lyrics)*
>
> *[It's too hot to fish, and too hot for golf,](https://genius.com/Mark-chesnutt-too-cold-at-home-lyrics)*
>
> *[Maybe he's no Romeo,](https://genius.com/Deniece-williams-lets-hear-it-for-the-boy-lyrics)*
>
> *[Psycho, alpha, disco, beta,](https://genius.com/Cypress-hill-psycobetabuckdown-lyrics)*
>
> *[So we can tango with these words,](https://genius.com/A-ap-ferg-tango-lyrics)*
>
> *[Who wears enlightened uniform?](https://genius.com/Pete-townshend-uniforms-corp-desprit-lyrics)*
>
> *[You're just a waste of lime,](https://genius.com/Ingrid-andress-waste-of-lime-lyrics)*
>
> *[I know you ain't used to a female alpha,](https://genius.com/Dua-lipa-future-nostalgia-lyrics)*
>
> *[Lets do the tango, do the tango,](https://genius.com/Louis-armstrong-takes-two-to-tango-lyrics)*
>
> *[India, you were born to rage, so come on!](https://genius.com/Dada-life-born-to-rage-india-version-lyrics)*
>
> *[I know He made you a snack like Oscar Proud,](https://genius.com/Justin-bieber-holy-lyrics)*
>
> *[I remember walking in the cold of November,](https://genius.com/Imagine-dragons-zero-lyrics)*
>
> *[Walking like the lost boys of Sierra Leone.](https://genius.com/The-roots-walk-alone-lyrics)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hidden message is

> CONGRATULATIONS: each of the lines contains one of the NATO spelling alphabet letters. (The first has Charlie, the second has Oscar, the third has November, etc.)
>
>  (The only exception is "lime", which should technically be "Lima".)

Comment: I really need to think up harder puzzles. You got it. I couldn't find any song lyrics with *Lima* in them, so that's why it's *lime*

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Maybe you'd have a better chance with Spanish/Portuguese songs like [this one](https://youtu.be/e7uOEV_Le1s) (extensive list [here](https://musicbrainz.org/search?query=lima&type=recording))

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Or if I can plug one of my favourite content creators, Jack Stauber: https://genius.com/Jack-staubers-micropop-lima-bean-man-lyrics

Comment: @marsnebulasoup could have fun with a typo, *The Girl from Ipalima* :P

Comment: Haha yes, should have used that